# Android: How to apply android:inputType globally on all EditText

Tags: android, mobile

how do I globally turn off auto-suggestions on all EditTexts of an application?
In other words, how do I do this `android:inputType="text"` on all EditText?

```
    <EditText android:id="@+id/et1"            
        android:inputType="text">
    </EditText>
```

Comment: I think it should work if you use a style for that... though I never tried it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can create an custom edittext and use this customview in your layouts

```
package com.talha.examples;
import android.content.Context;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class CustomEditText extends EditText {

    public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);


    }

    @Override
    public void setInputType(int type) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    }
}

<com.talha.examples.CustomEditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You manually modify each EditText. If you're creating them dinamically (eg. via code), then you already have references and can change the inputType at creation time. 
If you're creating them via xml, you problably have just a couple of buttons to modify and it's not even worth the time posting on stackoverlfow about it.